# How to definitively set the keyboard launguage?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, input-language

Every time I change the language of my keyboard in Ubuntu 14.04 and restart the machine, it changes back to what it was before.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **System Settings -> Text Entry**. The input source at the top of the list is default, and the one used at reboot or relogin. To change the default, move some other source to the top of the list.